# Where to download the latest Safari?

Tags: safari

Does anyone know where on apple.com I can get the latest Safari?  IE, Chrome, and Firefox all have "latest" version but I can not find a similar for Safari.

I would have guessed here, but no go.

http://support.apple.com/downloads/

Comment: This isn't programming related, nor, does it belong on this forum. There is a forum dedicated to Apple related products: apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply download Safari for OS X. You can get Safari updates that run on your installed OS X through the normal Apple Software Update or through the APP Store (I guess since 10.8).

Safari 6 is available for Mountain Lion and Lion only.

The latest version for PC is `Safari 5.1.7`. There's no version 6 available for PC. You can download it here: [Safari 5.1.7 for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1531).

Comment: You also need the script that checks the browser and suggests the update? Can you use PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Safari for Windows is no longer developed. Since all links in existing answers are dead, or do not provide expected information.
I would like to provide a working link here -> [SafariSetup](http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe)